# Lebesgue measure of sets and their symmetric difference

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I got this problem in my measure theory course and I my intuition says that this is really trivial, but i don't really know where to go with this

> let $\mu$ be a non-negative measure on $\sigma$-algebra $F$ of subsets of space $X$. Let $A$, $A_{n}$ $\in$ $F$. Show, that 
> if $\mu$ $\left( \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \right) \lt \infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}A_n = A$, then $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mu(A_n) = \mu(A)^*$. Does this imply $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mu(A_n \triangle A) = 0$? What's the connection between this and $^*$?

My intuition says that since none of those $A_n$'s are making measure of them big enough to equal infinity, then measures should approach each other, but I'm not sure how to prove this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what's the definition of $\mu(A)^*$?

Comment: I just used the * to label this equation and later ask about the connection between equations